# How to quickly calculate $\det(f(A))$, where $f(x)=2x^3+3x$ and A is a 3x3 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given $$A=\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 & -3 \\ 1 & 2 &3\end{matrix} \right)$$ how would one calculate $\det(f(A))$ most efficiently besides first raising $A$ to the 3rd power, adding the matrices and calculating the determinant (which is quite ugly in itself)? Or, better asked, is there any way to skip steps? Any observations that could help here?

Comment: $\det(AB)=\det(A)\cdot \det(B)$, thus factorize and compute, and before that simplify your matrix with a change of basis

Comment: Use $\det(2A^3+3A)=\det(A)\det(2A^2+3I)$, then there is not much of computing. I assume you can compute the square even by hand. For the determinant of a $3\times 3$-matrix use the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus), which is not too complicated.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "efficient".  Personally, I think that the most "efficient" way to perform this computation would be to plug it into a computer algebra system.

Comment: If function $f$ is defined by a polynomial or a series, $f(A)$ is amenable to an expression $f(A)=\alpha A^2 +\beta A + \gamma$ ... because of Cayley Hamilton theorem: $A^3=2A^2+4I$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is

$$\lambda^3-2 \lambda^2-4,$$

Cayley Hamilton theorem: gives $A^3=2A^2+4I$.

Therefore $f(A)=2 A^3+3A=4A^2+3A+8I.$

Then one has to end the calculation by hand...

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following: first you can compute $h(z):=\det(A-zI)$, now note that $f(z)=2z(z-\alpha )(z-\bar \alpha )$ for $\alpha =i\sqrt{3/2}$, then using the fact that $\det(M_1M_2)=\det(M_1)\det(M_2)$ for any two matrices $M_1$ and $M_2$ you have that

$$
\begin{align*}
\det(f(A))&=2^3\cdot  h(0)\cdot h(\alpha )\cdot h(\bar \alpha )\\
&=8\cdot h(0)\cdot h(\alpha )\cdot \overline{h(\alpha )}\\
&=8\cdot h(0)\cdot |h(\alpha )|^2
\end{align*}
$$

where the second equality follows because $h$ is a polynomial. I'm not sure about how efficient is this procedure, however it seems useful in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

As computed by Jean Marie, we know that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\chi_A(X)=X^3-2X^2-4=X^3-aX^2+bX-c$ with $(a,b,c)=(2,0,4)$.
Now, naming $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ the three roots (in $\mathbb{C}$) of $\chi_A$,
we have the relations between roots and coefficients of $\chi_A$:
$$a=\alpha+\beta+\gamma;\quad b=\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha;\quad c=\alpha\beta\gamma.$$

We further observe that
$$\renewcommand{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{rcccl}
\hfill\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2&{}={}&(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2-2(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)&{}={}&a^2-2b,\\[3pt]
\alpha^2\beta^2+\beta^2\gamma^2+\gamma^2\alpha^2&{}={}&(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)^2
-2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)\alpha\beta\gamma&{}={}&b^2-2ac.
\end{array}$$

Also $A$ is trigonalizable: there si some invertible $M\in\mathcal{M}_{3,3}(\mathbb{C})$ such that
$A=M^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha&*&*\\
0&\beta&*\\
0&0&\gamma
\end{pmatrix}M$.
For any complex polynomial $P$, we then have
$P(A)=M^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
P(\alpha)&\star&\star\\
0&P(\beta)&\star\\
0&0&P(\gamma)
\end{pmatrix}M$,
and $\det(P(A))=P(\alpha)P(\beta)P(\gamma)$.

Now let's proceed with $P(X)=2X^3+3X$.
We have: \begin{eqnarray*}
\det(P(A))&=&(2\alpha^3+3\alpha)\times(2\beta^3+3\beta)\times(2\gamma^3+3\gamma)\\
&=&\alpha\beta\gamma\times(2\alpha^2+3)\times(2\beta^2+3)\times(2\gamma^2+3)\\
&=&\alpha\beta\gamma\times\big[8(\alpha\beta\gamma)^2+12(\alpha^2\beta^2+\beta^2\gamma^2+\gamma^2\alpha^2)\\
&&\hskip8em{}+{}18(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2) + 27\big]\\[3pt]
&=&c\big[8c^2+12(b^2-2ac)+18(a^2-2b)+27\big]\\
&=&140.
\end{eqnarray*}
The advantage of this method is that we calculated no power of $A$ and no determinant either (at least in the “usual” way…).